# Need help for cpan installation and module directory

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to install `perl` module. But, I have this error:

> "Can't find C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat on PATH, '.' not in PATH".

And, when I use `cpan` from strawberry directory and try to install module, `perl` can't find it.

Comment: Please check the environment settings for the `Strawberry perl` path.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm these process done by you in your machine.

> [Go the System properties and Click `ENVIRONMENT Variables`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Ylz.jpg)
>
> [Add your Strawberry perl path in `USER variables`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knAcr.jpg) `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin`
>
> [Add your Strawberry perl path in `SYSTEM variables`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQq9A.jpg) `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin`

I hope this is clear for you.